# Systemd service that holds boot until it is exited successful

Tags: systemd, rhel, aide

In RHEL 8 i want to set up a systemd service that runs the "aide --check" command. This service should start as soon as the target local-fs.target is reached. However, the service should block the execution of all downstream systemd services while the aide check is running. In detail, no network, no graphical user interface and no login shell should be started as long as the Aide check has not been successfully completed.
If the check fails, the service should automatically put the system in the systemd target emergency.target.
I have already tried various combinations of Requires, After and Before statements in the systemd file, but this has not led to success. I hope someone can give me some crucial advice.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? Please show us your unit file.

Comment: Quick guess:  `[Unit] Before=local-fs.target [Install] RequiredBy=local-fs.target`  Then `systemctl enable` your unit to make `local-fs.target` `Requires=` your unit.